# React / Material UI complex styling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an issue related with styling in React / Material UI. I think is an issue related with TouchRipple from Material-UI

```
       <div key={indexP}>
        <Link className={classes.link} to={parent.link}>
          <ListItem button  selected={this.state.treeParentOpen[indexP] === true}  onClick={this.handleClick(indexP)}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <ParentIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={parent.title} />
          </ListItem>
        </Link>
        <Divider />
      </div>
```

I have the above code inside a `Drawer` component (this is a small extract just to exemplify), for a Sidebar menu.
The issue i am having is related with the styling interaction of the `ListItem` and `Link` Components.

If i take the `Link`  out of the code i have a normal `ListItem`ripple behaviour (onclick and offclick), everything is pretty and in grey shades.

When i had the `Link` to the code (as is), the ripple behaviour of the `ListItem` changes and onClick is Blue and offClick purple. How should i address the styling of the ripple effect associated with buttonBase used in `ListItem`.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried putting the `<Link />` component inside `<ListItem />` instead of having it wrap it? You could also use `button` prop and use `onClick` then use change the route via the router and not necessarily a link..

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. Yes at the moment i have a workaround. I basically use ```ListItem``` without the prop ```button``` which kills the ripple. But what i am really looking for is a suggestion for an approach on how to address the ripple. How could i define the ```const style = ...``` in a way that i can reach the button and respective ripple inside ```<ListItem button ...```.